# How to set state in parent from one child component and access the state in another child component using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to set the state in Parent component on clicking a button in child component. Also i want to access this state in other child component.

**what i am trying to do?**
On clicking upload button (UploadButton component) i want the state isDialogOpen to be set to true. and i want to access isDialogOpen state in UserButton component.

below is the snippet,

```
function Main() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/page1"
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <Layout>
                                <React.Suspense fallback={<PlaceHolder></>}>
                                    <child1 {...routeProps} />
                                </React.Suspense>
                            </Layout>
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/page2"
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <Layout>
                                <Child2 {...routeProps} />
                            </Layout>
                        )}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </React>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}


function Child1() {
    return (
        <UploadButton/>
    );
}

type Props = RouteComponentProps<{ itemId: string; productId: string }>;

function UploadButton({ match }: Props) { //here i set the state isDialogOpen
    const [isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handle_click = () => {
        setDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handle_click}/>

            {isDialogOpen && (
                <UploadForm/>
            )}
        </>
    );
}


function Child2() {
    return (
        <UserButton/>
    );
}

function UserButton() {
    return (
        <Icon/>
    );
}
```

In the above snippet, isDialogOpen state is set in UploadButton component.

Now i want to modify above snippet such that the Icon component in UserButton component is hidden if isDialogOpen is true.

i want to access this isDialogOpen state in UserButton component.

**what i have tried?**

I can define a function in main component that sets isDialogOpen to true when Upload button is clicked in UploadButton component. but this needs passing the function as prop from main component to Upload Button and similarly passing the state to UserButton from main component.

Is there some neat way to do this? i am new to typescript and react. could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox.

Answer (score 2):

You should define state value and function which update state as props respectively to child components as props. You can take example of the code which I provide bellow

```js
const Child1 = (props) => {
  return <div>This is the counter value {props.counter}</div>
}

const Child2 = (props) => {
        return <div>
            <h2>Here the button to update the counter</h2>
            <button onClick={props.update}>
        Update counter state in the parent
      </button>
        </div>
}

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        counter: 0
    }
  }
  
  updateCounter = () => {
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <Child1 counter={this.state.counter} />
      <Child2 update={this.updateCounter} />
    </div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can use the same component with context API and React **HOOKS** like this

```
import React, { useContext, useState} from 'react';

const CounterContext = React.createContext({
    counter: 0
});

const MainComponent  = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    const updateCounter = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }

    return <CounterContext.Provider value={
        counter,
        update: updateCounter
    }>
        <div>
            <Child1 />
            <Child2 />
        </div>
    </CounterContext.Provider>;
}


const Child1 = (props) => {
    const counter = useContext(CounterContext);
    return <div>This is the counter value {counter.counter}</div>
}

const Child2 = (props) => {
    const counter = useContext(CounterContext);

    return <div>
        <h2>Here the button to update the counter</h2>
        <button onClick={counter.update}>
            Update counter state in the parent
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want to usestate instead of this.state and this.setState.

Comment: I made update to use **hooks** and [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: thanks. wrappping contextprovider in main and having many components in main...hmm is there a way to use usehook and no context...using context provider is my second option since in my application i am wrapping more than 3 context providers.

Comment: Is there a way to define context within UploadButton component (as in my question snippet) this UploadButton is wher i actually set the state. and then create useHook which uses usecontext to get the state... that can be defined in the same file and can be exported. I have a vague idea but i am not getting it to implement.